# Can I set memory_limit higher then the machines ram?

Tags: php, file-upload, raspberry-pi

Upload is limited by the `memory_limit`. But is `memory_limit` limited by the machines ram? The [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) doesn't say anything about it.

My example at hand. A raspberry pi has 1GB ram and I want to upload a 2GB file.

Comment: dunno, but if your raspberry pi have a 1GB of swap space available, it should be okay. However, you don't necessarily need 2GB of ram to upload a 2GB file.

Comment: @Kitson88 you answered the question. Can you make an answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use 2GB of RAM instantly when you upload a 2GB file. Chunks of the file is uploaded and gets stored as a temp file until the upload has completed. Your best bet is to try it and set your PHP.ini to the following:

```
memory_limit = -1
post_max_size = **SIZE**
upload_max_filesize = **SIZE**
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following to top of your php file

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```